# Overlapping content the using position relative / absolute

Tags: html, css

I have the following code where `main` Content appears on top of header.

Is it possible to fix it, without adding any style to `main` tag?

```css
header {
  position: relative; 
}

.left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right">Right</h1>
</header>
<main>
  Content
 </main>
```

Comment: Where should main appear?

Comment: Add height to header

Comment: @j08691 Just under header

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I would prefer to not add a height to header as its content height might change

Comment: doe the left and right need to be absolute? Could you remove the `position: absolute` and replace it with `float: left` or `float:r right`? If not, why?

Answer (score 1):

You could use floats instead of absolute positioning:

```css
main {
  clear: both;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right">Right</h1>
</header>
<main>
  Content
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set something to be absolutely positioned, you take it out of the document flow.  This means that it stops affecting the layout of other elements.

Here, since you have set all the contents of `<header>` to be absolutely positioned, as far as the layout engine is concerned, there is nothing inside `<header>`, so its height will be zero.  This results in `<main>` being positioned at the very top because there's nothing taking up space above it.

If you want a header with some contents on the left and some on the right, consider using flexbox or CSS grid to lay out the contents of `<header>`.  Absolute positioning is not the right way to do that.